# Which Simple Injector Scoped lifestyle should I use during unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I'm writing integration tests that setup a container on each test setup. I'm reusing registration code, but I get an error when attempting to register a dependency with Lifestyle.Scoped I get this error:

> SetUp : System.InvalidOperationException : To be able to use the Lifestyle.Scoped property, please ensure that the container is configured with a default scoped lifestyle by setting the Container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle property with the required scoped lifestyle for your type of application.

What DefaultScopedLifestyle should I use in my case? The scope should really be a singleton, but remember that I am reusing registration code from the webapi app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For integration test scenarios the scoped lifestyles that can be used are [Per Lifetime Scope](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetimes.html#perlifetimescope) and [Per Execution Context Scope](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetimes.html#perexecutioncontextscope). Per Lifetime Scope allows defining a scope that is bound to a thread, while Per Execution Contest Scope allows defining a scope that will flow over async operations.